# Round bottom corners on Android Bitmap?

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

Hey all, what would be best practice for clipping the bottom borders of a Bitmap? Just manipulate the Bitmap itself or overlay an alpha mask drawable or ...?

*The whole story:*

I've a Listview which looks like the iPhone's grouped UITableView style. I would like to display a Bitmap in the last row, but for now the Bitmap overlaps my custom background drawable of the Listview cell.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fyi: I've found this code snippet: http://www.ruibm.com/?p=184 .

As in my case, I only wanted the bottom corners to be rounded, so I added an additional drawRect (with smaller height than the drawRoundRect) to the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer can be found here: [How do I create a ListView with rounded corners in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683185/android-listview-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: Sry, not really, this thread shows how to set a custom background to the listview (what I've done in a similar way actually), but the content does not get clipped anyway, so my Bitmap would still overlay the rounded corners.

alex

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing - but I wanted to do it right in the XML, rather than java code.

I have explained what I did in an answer on this question: [Android XML rounded clipped corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328166/android-xml-rounded-clipped-corners).

It was the masking that appealed to me - it can be overlaid over any layout, with minimal problems. Very easy to scale over a whole project, and to change the exact masking, by just modifying one 9Patch masking file.