# Android XML rounded clipped corners

Tags: android, xml, rounded-corners

I've setup a LinearLayout with the following drawable background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="#CCFFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

The problem I'm having is within the LinearLayout I have another LinearLayout element that sits at the bottom of it's parent. Since that doesn't have rounded corners its corners extend past the parents bottom left and right corners.

The drawable background on the Child LinearLayout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:src="@drawable/pedometer_stats_background" 
    android:tileMode="repeat"   
/>
```

The issue looks like this: http://kttns.org/hn2zm on the device the non-clipping is more apparent.

What is the best method to accomplish the clipping?

Comment: I'm guessing it will be solved with clever use of padding and margins

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What your describing sounds like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:shape="rounded">
   <LinearLayout android:background="@drawable/pedometer_stats_background">
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the inner layout is pushing outside the rounded corners because it isn't rounded.  You'll have to round the corners of your bitmap.  If you have a repeating bitmap you'll want to look at defining a nine-patch drawable.  Round your corners then define the portion of the graphic that can expand.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

It'd be nice if we could just add a bitmap to the shape drawable and have that be applied as a skin over whatever shape we're drawing.  And, I bet if you know what your doing you could create a Shape subclass that draws a bitmap, but that's not included in Android out of the box unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was trying to get away without custom shaping the bitmaps. Can't believe you can't stop children from bleeding out.

Comment: Well you can stop them, but it's not there out of the box.  With a little code and ingenuity you can create something that does that.

Answer (score 44):

**2018 Update**

A lot has changed in the last 7 years.

The best way to handle this type of layout these days is to use `CardView` which has built in support for rounded corners and many other newer UI features as well.

Apply the `cardCornerRadius` property to set the corners to round.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    .......
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

---

**Original**

I needed iPhone-style rounded layouts, with a grey background behind them. (sigh - always copying the iPhone)

I was frustrated I couldn't find a way to mask a layout. Most of the answers here say to use a background image, but this is not what I needed.

---

**Edit**: Previous answer suggested using a `FrameLayout` and setting the `android:foreground` drawable. This introduced some strange padding into the view. I have updated my answer to use simpler `RelativeLayout` technique.

---

The trick is to use a `RelativeLayout`; place your layout inside it. 
Below your layout, add another `ImageView`, setting its `background` to a suitable masking image frame. This will draw that on top of your other layout.

In my case, I made a 9Patch file which was a grey background, with a transparent rounded rectangle cut out of it.

[image: frame]

This creates the perfect mask for your underlying layout.

XML code is below - this is a normal layout XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <!-- this can be any layout that you want to mask -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Random text..." />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- FRAME TO MASK UNDERLYING VIEW -->
    <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/grey_frame"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mainLayout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note the `ImageView` at the bottom, aligned top & bottom to the main layout, with the masking image set:

- `android:background="@drawable/grey_frame"`

This references my 9Patch file - and masks the underlying layout by being drawn in the foreground.

Here is an example showing the grey rounded corners over a standard layout.

[image: maskedLayout]

hth

Comment: I've tried several approaches for rounded corners on ListViews and this one is definitely the most reliable. Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: This is definitely the best way. Also it allows your designers to go crazy and add drop shadows/glow to the rounded corners and you don't have to do some crazy <shape> drawing or anything.

Comment: I had fun with "always copying from iPhone." So true! :(

Comment: I use a similar trick but instead of drawing a 9-patch I draw 2 shapes around the image: 1 with rounded corners and 1 without. Requires an extra pass of course, but only pixels that actually need to be drawn. Plus I don't have to worry about aliasing issues or multiple bitmaps for different devices.

Comment: This does not work if you need transparent background

Comment: Ek sal dit bietjie probeer dankie

Comment: @Pierre hierdie antwoord is amper sewe jaar oud, en daar is deesdae beter metode om te gebruik. / This answer is 7 years old and there are better methods. I would always suggest these days to use `CardView` instead.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I actually want to use it for a standard ListView with nice rounded corners

Comment: @Pierre I would just put the `ListView` inside a `CardView` these days. Best luck whichever route you take.

Comment: Absolutely massive thanks for the CardView update to your original post @RichardLeMesurier - it saved me a lot of pain and anguish in trying to get rounded corners added to my Mapbox views and some MediaPlayer/SurfaceViews too!

Answer (score 15):

API level 21 (Lollipop) added [View.setClipToOutline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClipToOutline(boolean)). From Android documentation on [Defining Shadows and Clipping Views](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Clip):

> To clip a view to the shape of a drawable, set the drawable as the background of the view ... and call the View.setClipToOutline() method.

I tested this by setting a parent View's background to a GradientDrawable with a corner radius, and child Views are correctly cropped to match the same rounded corners of the parent.

Comment: API level 21 is Lollipop, not Jellybean

Comment: I didn't want to use CardView and View.setClipToOutline worked for me. You have to  set it to the parent view.