# Android Canvas.drawPicture not working in devices with ice cream sandwich

Tags: android, canvas, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, hardware-acceleration

I want to draw a `Picture` on a `Canvas` by

```
mCanvas.drawpicture(mPicture, mRect)
```

Using target API 7 `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>`, it works perfectly in devices with API<14, but in devices with Ice Cream Sandwich, it doesn't work. Apparently this is because canvas.drawPicture is not supported with Hardware Acceleration: [Unsupported Drawing Operations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)
I have tried to fix this by disabling the Hardware Acceleration in the Manifest:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

but still does't work.

Comment: my target API is 7 `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and solved by programmatically turning off hardware acceleration only on the view that will draw the `Picture`

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

However [setLayerType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType%28int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) is only supported since API 11. So use this method instead:

```
public static void setHardwareAccelerated(View view, boolean enabled){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        if(enabled)
            view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        else view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try replacing `drawPicture` with `drawBitmap`. The syntax is almost the same, you just need to pass a source rectangle (just make it the size of the image) and a paint (which if you're not editing the image can be null).

Comment: But I only have the Picture object. I use [link](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) to parse svg files and it only gives Picture or PictureDrawable objects.

Comment: You should be able to get a bitmap from a `PictureDrawable` with `getBitmap()`. I'm not sure what impact this will have on an SVG though.

Comment: ok. I used PictureDrawable and draw on canvas: `mPictureDrawable.setBounds(mRect);
 mPictureDrawable.draw(mCanvas);`   It works now, thanks. But still was hoping to use Picture instead of PictureDrawable