# android.graphics.Picture not being drawn in API 14+

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas, cyanogenmod

When i change the targetAPI in the manifest from 13 to 14 (or higher) the Picture no longer work. No matter what or how.

Example

```
    Paint bluepaint = new Paint();
    bluepaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    Picture pic = new Picture();
        Canvas testcanvas = pic.beginRecording(300, 300);
        testcanvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    pic.endRecording();

    canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 480, 480, bluepaint);

    canvas.drawPicture(pic);
```

This should draw a blue screen from the pic, it does so in API 13 and lower.
It does NOT draw the blue but only the red from the pure canvas.draw call.

I can't see any change from API 13 to 14 that would explain this.

However i am using cyanogenmod on a Galaxy S2 (so i can run 4.3), not sure if they change native stuff on cyanogen, switched to it couple of weeks ago.

Any idea where to look for answers or what could cause this ?

**edit**

working

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

NOT working

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Comment: my mistake, the canvas size of the pic doesnt really matter for filling calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `targetSdkVersion` is 14 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or higher then hardware acceleration is enabled by default for the whole app. [Unfortunately `Canvas.drawPicture()` is not supported if hardware acceleration is enabled](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported).

There are two way to fix this:

1. Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` to the `application` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml. This will disable hardware acceleration for your whole app.
2. You can use `Bitmap` and `Canvas.drawBitmap()` which is supported with hardware acceleration.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: after knowing the issue i found this solution to be the best for my case http://stackoverflow.com/a/14054331/1092271

Answer (score -1):

Use these dependency ... here 26.0.2 is a bug and Version 14 is not supportable. give these dependency:-

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

and Make SDK version:-

**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27  
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yeshveer.mygraphics"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"}
```

**

But you can try once with dependency without change SDK version.

and Remember canvas.restore(); dont use