# Giving hexagonal shape to custom view

Tags: android, view, shapes, mask, samsung-touchwiz

I had the same problem than Williams in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601400/how-to-give-hexagon-shape-to-imageview/24627494#24627494), and the solution provided by SceLus worked very well !

However, i'm facing another problem : the shape works correctly on my devices (Nexus 5 and 7 on 4.4.4), but when I test it on a Galaxy Tab 3 (running on 4.1.2), it doesn't work : i have a square shape instead of a hexagon shape.

Does someone has a idea about what causes this problem (It seems the problem come from the Android version because I tried in a Galaxy S2 also on 4.1). What can I do to have the hexagonal shape on devices running on 4.1 ?

Edit : I'm wondering if TouchWiz could be the problem actually...

Edit : view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); did the trick for me. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384613/android-canvas-drawpicture-not-working-in-devices-with-ice-cream-sandwich/14054331#14054331) if you have similar problems.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.