# Rounded Inner corners with transparent inside frame

Tags: android

I am trying to make a frame from code so that I can apply it to make rounded inner corners with a solid fill outside and transparent inside. ***Just like a solid rectangle with transparent oval inside.*** picture attached. I have tried few shape combinations all that available online displays the corners outside.

[image]

The inside should be transparent not white.
The image is taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328166/android-xml-rounded-clipped-corners) but the solution presented here is not what I am looking for I dont want to use a 9 patch drawable but would like to be created in code.

Please valid answers only.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all, create 3 `xml` `layout` in drawable folder:

1. First:  **frame.xml**
2. Second: **frame_build.xml**
3. Third:  **red.xml**

(You can change this name as you wish),

**frame.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:bottom="20dp" android:drawable="@drawable/red" android:top="-25dp" />
    <item android:bottom="15dp" android:drawable="@drawable/frame_build" android:top="5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" />
</layer-list>
```

**frame_build.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
    <corners android:radius="40dp" />
</shape>
```

**red.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="40dp" android:height="40dp" android:color="#B22222" />
    <padding android:left="8dp" android:top="-1dp" android:right="8dp" android:bottom="9dp" />
    <corners android:radius="-10dp" />
</shape>
```

Finally refer your view or layout to Frame XML as follow :

```
  android:background="@drawable/frame"
```

This tested and output as below image:

[image: Output image]

Hope this help .

Comment: Seems like what I just need, let me try then I'll mark it as answer

Comment: I've tried but its a black background not a transparent am I doing something wrong. I am using it in a framelayout and it should show the frames below it.

Comment: @user606669 add the same color for both framelayout and frame_build.XML , this will gave you the transparancy

Comment: @AndroidStack can you please explain the relation between the numbers, or use constants instead?

Answer (score 60):

create the following rounded_corner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="-10dp"
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="-10dp"
        android:top="-10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

add this below your imageView, which you want to apply the frame on it:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/my_image_view"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner" />
```

Comment: It's working great, but I don't understand why, can you explain please?

Comment: It is drawing a bigger 'oval stroke' on the rectangle that covers the rectangle's corners.

Answer (score 7):

tweaking @Nima K solution, to avoid using an extra View

create frame.xml @ drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="-10dp"
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="-10dp"
        android:top="-10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="20dp"
                android:color="@color/frame_color" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <stroke
                android:width="20dp"
                android:color="@color/frame_color" />

            <corners android:radius="40dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Then use it with 'android:background' attribute of your view

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/frame" />
```

[And this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlJzq.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe more simply;**

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:inset="-6dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <stroke android:width="12dp"
            android:color="#000000" />
    
        <corners android:radius="16dp" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```