# How should I override VideoView's onDraw in order for it to have transparent rounded corners?

Tags: android, android-videoview

Clearly using a background shape doesnt work in the case of VideoView
Also, there are lots of articles how to override onDraw for ImageView and make its corners round.

But how do I do it for a VideoView?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transparent rounded corners cannot be done with a `VideoView` or any `SurfaceView`, as according to the documentation:

> The surface is Z ordered so that it is behind the window holding its SurfaceView; the SurfaceView punches a hole in its window to allow its surface to be displayed.

With a `TextureView` it seems theoretically possible, as its supposed to behave like a normal view. However I was unable too: Tried Porter Duff modes of both the `TextureView` layer paint and a `ShapeDrawable` in the foreground of the parent `FrameLayout`.

With a `VideoView`, what you can do is make corners of a solid color. Use a 9-patch with transparent content and just the corners of a solid color and set in on an `ImageView` that gets drawn on top.

**Edit:** Check [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByG7hiDfOg6ub1NRcjBJQUFiTWs/edit?usp=sharing) example project.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: so it is possible? (referring to the last paragraph of what you said)

Comment: @J.Kowalski Yes, its possible. Check the example project I just added to the answer.

Comment: This is possible using a TextureView, for instance by using a CardView (see my answer)

Comment: Try this sample https://github.com/developer-anees/android-round-camera2video-preview

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this effect by putting a TextureView inside a CardView (from the support library).

You can then set corner radius and shadow on the CardView:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no easy way to do this. You could try this for example:

- place a video window under a ImageView window
- populate the ImageView with a solid color PNG that has a transparent shape in it
- use a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout to hold the two views as they allow views to overlap each other easily