# How to create circle or round VideoView in android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to create circle `VideoView` in android. I had tried with android shapes but its not working.

ring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="ring"

android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
android:useLevel="false" >

<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

<stroke 
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</shape>
```

Output screen shot

[image]

I'm expecting out put like this

[image]

**Is it possible to create exact rounded or circle `VideoView` in android. And also it will be support all resolution. I don't know how to achieve this, Please share your valuable ideas**

Comment: see my answer at [this ans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038633/circle-shape-for-viewpager#answer-33038935), same condition for you

Comment: can you check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300612/how-should-i-override-videoviews-ondraw-in-order-for-it-to-have-transparent-rou/23390070#23390070