# how to play youtube video in a custom circular view

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view, youtube-data-api, custom-view

I want to crop youtube video in a circular view while playing. How can I achieve this? I have tried it by embedding it in a linear layout and then making the background of the layout as a circle but the youtube player view remains in the rectangular shape in this case.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and background file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid
    android:color="#666666"/>
<size
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should show us what you have tried?

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi please check i have edited the question

Comment: are you not missing to close the `shape` tag ?

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi i have done that in my code

Comment: youttube playview height width set to match-parent and padding 10dp.and just check it

Comment: @dipali i had tried that as well earlier it was not working

Comment: put this line in youtubeplayer android:background="@drawable/circle"

Comment: setting background won't crop the video, as it is only a **background**. You should put your YouTube into a layout, which will crop it's children to the circle. Search for `android layout clip children circle`

Comment: @dipali No its not working the thing is that youtube player is not changing its shape no matter what i am doing with its parent layout . it remains rectangular in shape

Comment: refer this,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390070/1848157
more over you can customize it using this ,
https://github.com/airG/android-circular-expandable-videoview

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko by doing that video aspects ratio is not maintained it doesnt get fit into the circle it just gets croped

Comment: And that is exactly what you have asked: `I want to crop youtube video in a circular view while playing`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko crop means I want to fit that video into a circle while maintaining the aspect ratio of that video

Comment: that doesn't sound like crop. Can you draw a scheme of what you want?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517221/custom-layout-that-rounds-the-corners-of-its-content  see the circular image in this link i want my video to run like this. maintaining the aspect ratio

Comment: it should work exactly this way. How does it look for you now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167396/discussion-between-rohan-sharma-and-vladyslav-matviienko).

Answer (score 1):

First you create a CircleLayout class from below Link.

https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout/blob/master/src/ru/biovamp/widget/CircleLayout.java

Add this styleable into you values.

```
<declare-styleable name="CircleLayout">
    <attr name="innerRadius" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="sliceDivider" format="reference|color" />
    <attr name="innerCircle" format="reference|color" />
    <attr name="angleOffset" format="float" />
    <attr name="angleRange" format="float" />
    <attr name="layoutMode">
        <enum name="normal" value="1" />
        <enum name="pie" value="2" />
    </attr>
    <attr name="dividerWidth" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

After set your YouTubePlayerView in your layout like below:-

```
<packageName.CircleLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layoutMode="pie"
        app:angleOffset="90.0">

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </packageName.CircleLayout>
```

Your YouTube View like below image:-

[image]