# Rounded corners android image buttons

Tags: android, imagebutton

I am trying to round corners on an android ImageButton, the code looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
            android:src="@drawable/friends"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_marginRight="62dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Basically our output is an ImageButton but it has squared corners, we are trying to round off the corners.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791449/add-rounded-corners-to-custom-view. use a selector and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771367/create-button-with-rounded-corners-in-android

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use [**Shape**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) in android to make the rounder corners

create the xml file named it as `roundcorner.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#33DDFF" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
```

In your ImageButton add this attribute `android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"`

```
<ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:src="@drawable/friends"
                android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_marginRight="62dp" />
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it is working perfectly. 
I am wondering why there isn't any xml attribute so that we can do it faster..!

Comment: this solution was not working for me, but after setting the android:shape property to "ring" it worked. I think you probably missed this part.
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring">

Answer (score 10):

You could use a selector made of shape drawables as background, for example :

> rounded_bg.xml (to be created in res/drawable-nodpi folder)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

Create another one, changing the color referenced in `solid android:color="#ffffff"` , for example to `solid android:color="#ff0000"` and name that file `rounded_bg_selected.xml`

Create the selector (also in res/drawable-nodpi), name it `selectable_button_bg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_bg_selected" />
    <item  android:state_focused="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_bg" />
</selector>
```

Then reference it in your layout :

```
<ImageButton
     android:background="@drawable/selectable_button_bg"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/imageButton"
     android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
     android:src="@drawable/friends"
     android:padding="1dp"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2"
     android:layout_marginRight="62dp" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Create `image_rounded_corner.xml` inside /res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#000000" /> 
  <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#776da8" /> 
  <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp" /> 
  <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
  </shape>
```

Call the image_rounded_corner.xml file with `android:background`

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/myimage" 
           android:src="@drawable/icon"
           android:background="@drawable/image_rounded_corner" />
```

or use an [**Draw 9-patch**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) file as "Artoo Detoo" suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:
Put this in res/drawable folder

**my_gradient.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="100dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#090" />

</shape>
```

In your ImageButton Just put:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_gradient"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static Bitmap toRoundCorner(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    return output;
  }
```

this code will help you.(From a chinese article:http://www.cnblogs.com/liuweiming/archive/2012/04/23/2466074.html)

Comment: Very nice, as far as I can tell this is the only solution that actually rounds the bitmap corners. The answers that set a background just draw a rounded outline under the image, but the image corners are still square. To process a bitmap that's already assigned to an ImageButton you can do something like this:
BitmapDrawable bmd = (BitmapDrawable)btn.getDrawable();
btn.setImageBitmap(toRoundCorner(bmd.getBitmap(), 15));

Comment: @Georgie I am a bit late to the party, but have a look at my solution since that probably works a LOT quicker than this

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me programmatically:

```
val gradientDrawable = GradientDrawable()

gradientDrawable.shape = GradientDrawable.OVAL
gradientDrawable.cornerRadius = <YOUR CORNER RADIUS HERE>

yourView.clipToOutline = true
yourView.background = gradientDrawable
```