# ImageButton background with XML

Tags: android, xml, background, imageview, imagebutton

I am trying to make a round Android ImageButton. To do so, I write the following code according to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633637/rounded-corners-android-image-buttons).

**In my main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Invite Activity."  />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/round"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
        android:padding="50dp"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

**In my res/drawable/roundcorner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#33DDFF" />
    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
</shape>
```

But the code doesn't work. The output is like below
[image: Image1]

However, when I change **ImageButton** to **ImageView** in **main.xml**

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/imageButton"
     android:src="@drawable/round"
     android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
     android:padding="50dp"  />
```

It works as below

[image: Image2]

I am confused since as I know ImageButton inherits from ImageView. Why does it work differently? Is there anyway to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the full xml...

Comment: i have updated the full xml

Answer (score 0):

Make your src as  android:src="@drawable/roundcorner", or make it transparent so you can see the rounded background behind it.

Comment: The result is like [this](http://imgur.com/YQMtoKy). So it seems that the big image cover up the button... is there a way to make the image fit the round button (crop the image to fit the round button)?

Comment: Check this if you want the same like imageview output.   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/round" />