# Background image for a button in android

Tags: android, button, layout, background-image, android-linearlayout

I am trying to add a background image for a button and it is working, but not as I expected.

[1st picture (without background)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9iYq.png)

[2nd picture (with background)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6srV.png)

I would like the background to cover only the button. In other words, the image should have the same form as the 2 buttons from above (I'm talking about the round corners and a bit smaller size).

Here is the xml of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:onClick="playerStats"
        android:text="@string/plStats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Button

        android:text="@string/comp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/calendar"
        android:text="@string/calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you tried using `scaletype`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its easy to do that

you should use ImageButton and remove those Buttons for example

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
    android:text="@string/calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

also if you want to remove the background of that button you can use :

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your layout with these layout...It can be helpfil for you

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:onClick="playerStats"
        android:text="@string/plStats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
  <View    ////I HAVE ADDED VIEW WHICH IS TRASNPARENT TO SEPRATE THE BUTTONS
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"

    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
</View>


<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <Button

        android:text="@string/comp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>

  <View ////I HAVE ADDED VIEW WHICH IS TRASNPARENT TO SEPRATE THE BUTTONS
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"

    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
</View>


<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/calendar"
        android:text="@string/calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<View  ////I HAVE ADDED VIEW WHICH IS TRASNPARENT TO SEPRATE THE BUTTONS
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"

    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
</View>
```

Comment: I have tried your code, however it's not exactly what i need; it just puts some space between the buttons

Comment: @LerulLer ...What you else , actually want bro??

Comment: I want the image of the third button (from the second picture) to have the same size/form as the third button from the 1st picture (if you look closely, the image from the second picture is a bit bigger than the button from the 1st picture)

Comment: @LerulLer ..You have to use the dimen approach for it...You can specify the height of buttons of the respective dimen folders of android

Comment: @LerulLer ... I have edited the answer..plz check it...In place of FILL_PARENT inside the LINERLAYOUT..i replaced to the MATCH_APRENT....It will work for you..You can try it...and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is: You need to edit your image background (make it a little smaller and have corner) - it can be done easily by using Photoshop
Than use [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/tools/help/draw9patch.html) tool for make 9-patch image (9-patch images can automatically resize to accommodate the contents of the view and the size of the screen)

Answer (score 0):

The "without background" button is actually displaying it default background, so **setting new background will override that corner-rounded-gray thing**...

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633637/rounded-corners-android-image-buttons).

I recommend using `ImageButton` with `android:src` instead.