# Picasso : Load Layout into Button instead of drawable

Tags: java, android, xml

Here's what I have :

MyButton.java

```
public class MyButton extends AppCompatButton implements Target {
public MyButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}


@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
}

@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

}

@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

}}
```

In my Fragment I have this :

```
MyButton BteyoutubePlay;
BteyoutubePlay = (MyButton) v.findViewById(R.id.BteyoutubePlay);
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.gris_xml).into(BteyoutubePlay);
```

And here's my gris_xml.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#8E8D8D"/>
        <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/g_drawable"></item>
```

So everything here works, BUT Picasso won't load my layout, it's working if I replace :

```
 Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.gris_xml).into(BteyoutubePlay);
```

by :

```
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.g_drawable).into(BteyoutubePlay);
```

So basically putting the image, instead the layout, I'm using the layout because it makes the button corners rounded and I add a color in it ...

If somebody know how I can achieve this, it will be really helpful !

Thanks :)
Cordially,
LooK

Comment: Simply use directly don't use Picasso for xml

Comment: hmm but I have to recreate all my buttons in photoshop then with corners ... I'm sure there's a way to do it without recreating everything

Comment: U can try like this ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633637/rounded-corners-android-image-buttons

Comment: Hello thanks, already tried it, but Picasso "erase" the android:background :/