# Rounded corners in Android ImageButton doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, image, button

Is there something wrong with my code?
`round_corner.xml` (I put it in drawable)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#FFFF0F" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    </shape>
```

I think what's not working is the code in my imageButton

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
        android:src="@drawable/my_pic"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

It doesn't give me any error . It just didn't make my image rounded . Any ideas?

Comment: You want to Round The Imagebutton ?

Comment: maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633637/rounded-corners-android-image-buttons

Comment: yes but it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: @ dexter : i have tried but it didnt work so i asked here.

Comment: your Image is Covering the Whole ImageButton ?

Comment: @user_22 that will not work , check answers in the question I linked

Comment: @redman : i have seen that post and i tried that but is not working with mine. so just see my code and see whats wrong with it

Comment: @user_22 no you havn't seen yet , applying shape won't make your drawable rounded  . Try different way mentioned in my previous link, I would suggest this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/40150715/6478047

Comment: @FaizMir : yes. any solutions?

Comment: have you tried to **run the app**, or only looked at Android Studio preview?

Comment: yeah wait......

Comment: @user_22 check my answer

Answer (score 1):

First Create a shape.xml

```html
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#FFFF0F" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    </shape>
```

use this xml:

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"

    android:elevation="4dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumbnaill"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/maxresdefault"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is Your Output :)
Please Note it will not show the radius on Xml preview run the app it will appear

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `CardView` instead of Image Button

You can achieve the same effect by `CardView` by this code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_pic"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"/>
```