# Rounding top and bottom corners of a listview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

This is my issue I can't seem to round the edges on the bottom of my listview.

[image: LIST VIEW EXCEEDS EDGES]

I've tried a couple of methods where you create a shape for the backgroup resource, tried it programmatic ally and in the layout xml's but it does not do anything at all.

Like I either did it wrong which I doubt since I am familiar with shapes, or something else interferes with my attempts.
Either way I need help is what I'm getting at.

Here's some of the xml's that make up what you're looking at.

This makes up the actual dialog. (settings_dialog.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#BB000000"
                android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        style="@style/CloseButtonStyle"
        android:id="@+id/ivCancel_SD"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rlContainer_SD"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rlContainer_SD"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rlContainer_SD"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/SettingsDialogStyle"
        android:id="@+id/rlContainer_SD"
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            style="@style/SettingsHeaderStyle"
            android:id="@+id/tvSettingsLabel_SD"
            android:layout_width="330dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/sd_header_label"/>


               <ListView
        style="@style/SettingsListStyle"
        android:id="@+id/lvOptions_SD"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_listview_corners"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvSettingsLabel_SD"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is located in my styles.xml with a bunch of other stuff that has no relation to this.

```
<style name="SettingsListStyle">
    <item name="android:divider">@color/table_divider_color</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">2dp</item>
</style>
```

And this makes up a list_item. (settings_list_item.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:padding="5dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/SettingsOptionNameStyle"
            android:id="@+id/tvOptionName_SLI"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            style="@style/SettingsOptionDescStyle"
            android:id="@+id/tvOptionDesc_SLI"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the shape I used to try and round the edges.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/bg_listview_corners" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

I've also tried this piece for the shape.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/bg_listview_corners" android:shape="rectangle"> 
        <corners 
         android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" 
         android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

This is all the information I think you'll need to help me on my way.
In case I missed some information or you just have questions don't hesitate to ask.

**Update 1:**
I figured out it somehow only shapes the container of the listview but not the listview itself.
Any ideas?

Comment: try to give more padding from bottom and top to your ListView

Comment: and where Do You set the shape?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs in the listview in settings_dialog.xml

Comment: can You post this please?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs look in the topmost codepiece, I call the background there in the listview element. Also I added another codepiece which is my shape

Answer (score 1):

- you can increase the padding (paddingRight, paddingLeft, and paddingBottom)

  ```
  <style name="SettingsListStyle">
  <item name="android:divider">@color/table_divider_color</item>
  <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingTop">40dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingLeft">7dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingRight">7dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingBottom">3dp</item>
  ```
- or use mask background over the listview (like this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8313096/5891893) which use 9-Patch as mask, or you can use your "bg_listview_corners.xml" background for the mask)

Comment: Padding wouldn't work as it since that would mess up the alignment of the list with the rest of the layout. I ended up solving it with a mask, thanks for  the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom background drawable selector file called custom_list.xml in your drawable folder with this code in it

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_default"/>

</selector>
```

then create another file list_default.xml in your drawable folder with this code in it

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#1c95a0"
    android:startColor="#1c95a0" />
<corners android:radius="5dip" />

</shape>
```

finally set the background property of the list view to

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_list"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a mask as suggested by @Sally here is how I changed it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#BB000000"
                android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        style="@style/CloseButtonStyle"
        android:id="@+id/ivCancel_SD"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rlContainer_SD"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rlContainer_SD"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rlContainer_SD"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/SettingsDialogStyle"
        android:id="@+id/rlContainer_SD"
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            style="@style/SettingsHeaderStyle"
            android:id="@+id/tvSettingsLabel_SD"
            android:layout_width="330dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/sd_header_label"/>


        <ListView
            style="@style/SettingsListStyle"
            android:id="@+id/lvOptions_SD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvSettingsLabel_SD"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="800dp"
            android:layout_height="600dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_listview_corners"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I added an `ImageView` on top of the relative layout matching the container.
This is the drawable I used for masking the layout.(bg_listview_corners.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="12dp"
                android:color="@color/app_night_sky_color" />
            <padding android:left="6px"
            android:top="6px"
            android:right="6px"
            android:bottom="6px"/>

            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

            <stroke
                android:width="6dp"
                android:color="@color/popup_bg_color" />

            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```