# Unable to achieve rounded ListView on Android 2.2

Tags: java, android, exception, listview, drawable

I have a custom drawable rounded_corner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF" android:endColor="#FFFFFF" 
            android:angle="90"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

I apply it via code:

```
listView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
```

but I get the error:

```
5-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.stocktwits.activity/org.stocktwits.activity.WatchlistActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/rounded_corner.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02000d
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/rounded_corner.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02000d
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7393)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at org.stocktwits.activity.WatchlistActivity.setupUI(WatchlistActivity.java:184)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at org.stocktwits.activity.WatchlistActivity.onCreate(WatchlistActivity.java:127)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     ... 18 more
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4<gradient> tag requires 'angle' attribute to be a multiple of 45
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:678)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
05-09 20:39:17.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1299):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
```

How can I diagnose this? The resource exists.

Comment: Note that if you specify a "simple" (not a selector) drawable as a background, it won't change when you navigate using the trackball/dpad, when you press it, when you long press it, etc. Consider all the downsides before going down this path (or provide all the other states as rounded thingamajigs as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the "caused by" part of the stacktrace:
Binary XML file line #4 tag requires 'angle' attribute to be a multiple of 45

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to 90 and still got an XMLPullParserException.

Comment: Updated my question with the new XML, and new stacktrace.

Comment: Just to eliminate the most obvious things; have you saved the file after editing?

Comment: Yes, and it exists in drawable-hdpi

Comment: This is very puzzling. The comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683185/android-listview-with-rounded-corners indicate that others have remedied your exact problem by changing the angle to a multiple of 45.

Comment: Btw, there isn't much use with a gradient from white to white. Maybe you can simply remove the gradient element?

Answer (score 0):

try writing this
*corners android:radius="7dp"*
instead of 

    corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"


Put this .xml file in drawable folder, and try using
  
  listView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable rounded_corner.xml);

Comment: How can I get mine to have a white background?

Answer (score 0):

Heres how I added rounded border around my list

```
<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@id/android:list"
 android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0"
 android:background="@drawable/app_user_list_drawable" android:fadeScrollbars="true"
 android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"  android:layout_margin="10dip"
 android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" android:paddingLeft="10dip"
 android:paddingRight="10dip" android:divider="#7D7D7D" android:dividerHeight="1px"/>
```

app_user_list_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
<padding android:left="0dip" android:top="1dip" android:right="0dip"
 android:bottom="1dip"/>
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#7D7D7D"/>
</shape>
```

This created a simple white border around my list with round edges. The padding in the listview was put to give a bit space or will look awkward when rows are added.

Comment: i can't seem to get mine to have a white background. How can I do that?