# Custom ListView Background in Android

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to get
[this](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html#/test/docs/lists/lists-nested.html) effect on a  ListView in native Android? There are other alternatives like creating the list in HTML5 CSS and using phonegap etc; but it would be nice if it can be done by modifying the default behavior of Android ListView . Any ideas?

Comment: I think it is possible, can you please specify specifically what effect you are looking for ?

Comment: Background of alternate list items, especially the bevel effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) work?

If you want rounded/beveled corners on the `ListView`, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683185/android-listview-with-rounded-corners) out.

As for the individual items' backgrounds, you will probably have to make the graphics yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I'm interested in the graphics part of the view, the background etc.

Comment: So, you just want to have rounded corners on the `ListView` and make the items have that sleek background? If so, I've amended my response.