# How to make an ordinary view to have rounded corners in code without xml

Tags: android, rounded-corners

Is there any way to make an ordinary view to have rounded corners in code completely without xml? Overriding onDraw is not the way I'm looking for,either. I have read the posts:
[How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)

and [How do I create a ListView with rounded corners in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683185/android-listview-with-rounded-corners)

, but they are not what I'm looking for.