# How to make rounded corner relativeLayout without using shape

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, rounded-corners

I want to make my RelativeLayout rounded cornered, without using `Shape`. How can I implement this?

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="350dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648275/6532155

Comment: @Kavita_p Thanks for your reply, but i want resolve that in xml file.

Comment: i use cardview and set card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp". my problem solved.