# Navigation component: Show dialog with rounded corners

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, material-components-android

I am using the Android [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) to show a `DialogFragment`. This also works fine, but now I want to have rounded corners on the dialog.

I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57843956/298288) that I could use the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` of the Material Design Components (which my app uses anyways), but as the navigation component displays the `DialogFragment` for me, I have no access to the DialogBuilder that the navigation component uses? Or is there any way to access it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I have no access to the DialogBuilder that the navigation component uses'? `DialogFragment` lets you use any type of Dialog by overriding `onCreateDialog()`, Navigation has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Thanks, you are right - I am still new to Android and understood something wrong. Got it now :-) For others: Here is a detailed blog post about `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` on medium, also mentioning `DialogFragment` and `onCreateDialog()` https://medium.com/over-engineering/hands-on-with-material-components-for-android-dialogs-75c6d726f83a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation doesn't control what type of dialog is being created - that is the responsibility of the `DialogFragment` and specifically its [`onCreateDialog()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle)) method.

It is in `onCreateDialog()` that you'd use `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` to create your dialog with rounded corners.