# Android ListView with radius top bottom

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Dose anyone know how to make the radius can always show on top when I scrolling the ListView?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am using BaseAdapter to implement the first & last item background.

Here is the adapter code,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(this.dataset != null && !this.dataset.isEmpty() && this.dataset.size() > 0){
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.corner_list_item_layout, null);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        if(holder == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();  
            holder.item = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.corner_list_item_relativelayout);
            holder.label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.corner_list_item_label);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }           

        if (position == 0) {
            if (position == (this.getCount() - 1)) {
                holder.item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_list_corner_round_light);
            } else {
                holder.item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_list_corner_round_top_dark);
            }
        } else if (position == (this.getCount() - 1)) {
            if(position % 2 == 0){
                holder.item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_list_corner_round_bottom_dark);
            }else{
                holder.item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_list_corner_round_bottom_light);
            }

        } else {
            if(position % 2 == 0){
                holder.item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_list_corner_middle_dark);
            }else{
                holder.item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_list_corner_middle_light);
            }
        }

        String str = String.valueOf(this.dataset.get(position));        
        holder.label.setText(str);

    }
    return convertView;
}`
```

Comment: Should I custom a ListView rather than custom the BaseAdapter

Comment: Just try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1683195/940096) and [this](http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/android-practice-listview-with-round-corner/)

Comment: I wanna to do this likely have a layer with inside radius to cover the first & last DISPLAY item.

Comment: Here i suggest you to take a [library](http://listview.android-libraries.com/) for rounded corner listview. It will give whatever you required.

Comment: Have you tried out that library?

Comment: Waiting the library.....

Answer (score 2):

1. Place the ListView inside any layout.
2. Prepare a 9-patch border image and place this as a background to the Layout.

[image]

Comment: I am using 9patch background, but still cannot do that

Comment: @Rebecca I have mentioned to use this as background of Layout, not a background inside Row items.