# How to add many strings in a edittext and set background image to each String?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to add many strings in a editext and set background of each String and remove each String on action perform device keyboard delete key.

[image] 
I am upload follwing image screenshot of path application in which strings is shown in edittext .I want to use same functionality please help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the event:

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {           
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                /* Delete Rows or use listItemAdapter to refresh a list */
                return true;
            }
            /* Write the rows or use a listItemAdapter to customize a list */
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is have each text item as a TextView all in a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation. Use a shape drawable to set the background drawable of the TextViews.

There is an example of this [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1683195/838023)