# Android - Layout help needed

Tags: android, listview, layout

[image]

I am looking for a suggestion how to create a layout which looks like the image above.
I can't figure out how the area in white is done.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, if I am not clear. I can't get my head around creating the layout as per the image. Is it a layout within  a layout, or is there some other way to achieve this.

Comment: For what I can see, you are using a ListView, or trying to, so you only have to define a list_item_layout. I recommend to use RelativeLayout, as it gives you more power. In order to have the round corners, you can use a nine-patch image that includes the round corners.

Comment: Thanks. So this will have basically two components in the listview. One for showing the mins section on the left and another one for the rest of it. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Yes, you can have a relative layout, with two relative layout children, one in the left with the mins, and one in the left with the other info. Of course, each relative layout, can also contains as many layout you as you need. Define the top layout with width="match_parent" and heigth="wrap_content".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Grav- Gravity/Layout Gravity
- Rel Lay - Relative Layout
- Txt.V - TextView
- Img.V - Image View
- L.L - LinearLayout
- Ornt - Orientation
- Hoz - Horizontal
- Ver - Vertical

Set left Layout's L.Height to `match_parent`, Right Layout's L.Height to `wrap_content` set `min-height` to right.layout.

If RelativeLayout is used in Left layout, use `align_parentTop` `center_horizontal` `align_parentBottom` respectively.

You *might not get the same while working in eclipse*, but will get the required in *Device/Emulator.* ***Note, your effort is needed.***

[image: Custom ListView]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial on customizing a ListView (Scroll down to Section 1.4): http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

If you're looking to make rounded corners you can look at this post:
[How do I create a ListView with rounded corners in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683185/how-do-i-create-a-listview-with-rounded-corners-in-android)

Comment: The tutorial explains list views in general, and I think it will give you a better understanding of how to customize list views.