# Android simple listview background

Tags: android, android-listview

Im trying to set my list view like the image im attached.Please anyone help me.
Thanks in advance

[image: demo image]

Comment: [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) for background? (and transparent list items, cache color etc.)

Comment: set transparent background to listview items, and set desired color or add image to background attribute of listview.

Comment: It seem a job for a 9 patch (not a Gradient, since a Gradient doesn't sow **stripes**). The problem is that you have no control on how much the stripes grow in height.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683185/how-do-i-create-a-listview-with-rounded-corners-in-android/1683195#1683195

Answer (score 2):

Well I can only think of a workaround, where in your `getView` (in the adapter) you set the background according to the position of the row. In other words, the bigger the `pos` int the "darker" the background.

Comment: `the bigger the pos int the "lighter" (more yellowish) the background`, in this case. But, yes, it's a valid solution, +1.

Answer (score 1):

I would set a gradient as a background for the list, like this:

```
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/orange"
            android:centerColor="@color/middlecolor"
            android:endColor="@color/yellow"
            android:angle="0" />
```

and then set a drawable with a line or similar as a background of each cell.

Answer (score 1):

Create a drawable for your gradient:

drawable/mybackground.xml

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="@color/red"
            android:startColor="@color/orange"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Remember to declare "red" and "orange" colors:

values/color.xml

```
<color name="orange">#0000FF</color>
<color name="red">#FFA500</color>
```

Finally, set your drawable as ListView background:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mybackground" />
```